# Vistas en android studio en pantallas pequeñas

Tags: android, android-studio, vistas

lo que pasa es lo siguiente estoy haciendo una aplicación, cuando la prueba en dispositivos con alta resolución se ve bien, pero cuando lo hago en dispositivos con una pantalla pequeña se ve cortado, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que permita deslizar hacia hacia abajo para ver el resto la interfaz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar más de como lo tienes, muestra el código del xml y cómo se ve, para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: pero como puedo añadir una imagen no me da la opción

Comment: Le das editar, y en la parte del cuerpo hay como unas opciones, ahí está la de añadir imagen y la subes

Comment: Cual es el layout? agrega una imagen del problema, por favor edita tu pregunta,revisa [ask] , saludos.

Comment: listo ya agregue una imagen, intente añadir el código en xml pero no me deja

Comment: Simplemente colocalo yo te ayudo a acomodarlo, mira las ayudas que se te ofrecen a la hora de editar o de escribir algunas preguntas

Comment: Y sube ambas imagenes, como se ve en la resolución más pequeña y la normal

Comment: En capturas no, copia el codigo, y pegalo en la pregunta

Comment: no me deja dice da error

Comment: que error sale?

Comment: Tu publicación parece contener código que no tiene el formato apropiado para código. Aplica una sangría de cuatro espacios a todo el código mediante el botón de código de la barra de herramientas o el método abreviado del teclado CTRL+K. Para obtener más ayuda de edición, haz clic en el ícono [?] de la barra de herramientas.
Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles.
Las imágenes pueden ser muy útiles para explicar un problema, pero por favor evita usarlas para mostrar el código fuente. El texto es fácilmente formateable (botón {}) y más legible.

Comment: A primera vista el layout que tienes no es muy adecuado en lo que hace, intenta implementar linear layout que es mucho más facil para acomodar las cosas que pongas, para mover los elementos hacia izquierda o derecha, es mejor utilizar `gravity` ó `layout-gravity` ya que con margenes puede desacomodar muchas cosas

Comment: ok gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: Te dejo algunas guías para que puedas guiarte [Linear Layour](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear?hl=es) , también una forma de hacer las vistas responsive, es con [Weight Sum](https://codeday.me/es/qa/20181212/18212.html), alguna duda que tengas me puedes decir o creamos una sala en el chat para irte ayudando

Comment: @JesusContreras revisa la respuesta que te dí a ver si te gusta más

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo ya te había comentado, una opción para hacer mejor manejo de los elementos en un `layout`, es el `LinearLayout` y se adapta a la necesidad que tengas, y una forma de que funcione responsive, es con `WeightSum` por lo tanto podrías dejarlo sin un `ScrollView` un ejemplo de utilizarlo sería:

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <Button
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_gravity="left">

</LinearLayout>
```

Explicando un poco el `weightSum` es el tamaño al cual se va a acoplar en el layout, en este caso el `LinearLayout` tiene un tamaño de 10, que ese sería como el 100% y el `button` que está dentro tiene un tamaño o peso de 1, que sería el 10% de esos 100% por lo tanto los elementos que crees dentro del `LinearLayout` se irán acoplando de acuerdo a su tamaño, en cuanto al `layout_gravity` es una forma de colocar el elemento a donde le digas, y así evitas acomodarlo con `margin` ya que el `margin` se puede desacomodar, alguna duda me la comentas o alguna corrección, otra cosa que ayuda para que sea adaptable a cualquier tipo de resolución es ésta [Cómo adaptar una aplicación a la resolución de pantalla en Android](https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/adaptar-aplicacion-resolucion-pantalla-android) consiste en copiar la carpeta layout y agregarle el tipo de resolución **(hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdip, xxxhdip)** lo cual se reconoce cómo si fuera grande, pequeña, mediana y así, y lo adaptas al tipo de pantalla modificando cada layout en una de estas para que así se acomode según la resolución y ya la app detectaría que layout tomar dependiendo de la pantalla, para mayor profundidad en el tema, revisa el enlace, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos!!